# JTextArea not showing text as desired

Tags: java, swing

What I want:

I have a JPanel over which there is a JTextarea and a JButton. After Button is pressed, I want a certain text (which varies as per if-else statements) to be shown inside JTextArea.

Structure:

1. I have a string variable called `yourphone`

   `String yourphone;`
2. Inside `ActionListener` of the `JButton`, there are if-else statements, something like this

   `if(R==120)
   {
       yourphone = "Galaxy S4";
   }

   if(R==130)
   {
       yourphone = "Xperia Z ultra";
   }`
3. This is how my JTextArea looks like

   `JTextArea txtrphone = new JTextArea();
   txtrphone.setText(yourphone);
   txtrphone.setRows(5);
   txtrphone.setBounds(68, 84, 285, 148);
   result.add(txtrphone);`

Problem

Its isn't working.

When I click the `JBUtton`, nothing happens. Nothing appears in the `JTextArea`.

Comment: `R==120` and `R==130`  here what is `R` ? Moreover add an `else` and assign string like `No model found`. Then you come to know the problem

Comment: R is another int variable. It is calculated as per user choices on previous JPanels. I'm trying to make a simple thing, survey type questions and then answers in the final. Check this out for more details. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507611/add-numeric-values-to-a-variable-in-actionlistener-to-show-variable-result

Comment: check whether your program counter goes into if and else statement or not

Comment: Okay tried it. In else statement I put, yourphone = "NO results"; But still upon execution, JTextArea doesn't show anything.

Comment: write print statements in if and else and check whether they are printed or not

Comment: First of all, do you have an an `actionLisener` registered with your button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put:

```
txtrphone.setText(yourphone);
```

in your action listener

You'll need to call setText(String) whenever you want to actually update the value of the text area.